# How to add dynamically property for the parameter of React setState method

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I use reactjs + typescript on my project.

I use this lines of code :

```
if (reinitGridState) { 
   this.setState({
        isbusy: false,
        itemsList: data,
        colList: columns,
        gridState: this.initGridState,
        gridData: process(data, this.initGridState)
    });
} else {
    this.setState({
        isbusy: false,
        colList: columns,
        itemsList: data,
        gridData: process(data, this.state.gridState)
    });
}
```

And I want to remove the duplicate call of `this.setState`

I try this :

```
let newState = {
    isbusy: false,
    colList: columns,
    itemsList: data,
    gridData: process(data, this.state.gridState),
}

if (reinitGridState)
    newState.gridState = this.initGridState;

this.setState(newState);
```

But an error occured : `Property 'gridState' does not exist on type '{ isbusy: boolean; colList: DisplayGridColumn[]; itemsList: any; gridData: DataResult; }`

How can I specify a type for variable `newState` to add it dynamically the property `gridState` and satisfy the type wanted for `setState` ?

PS : I don't want to use this `newState["gridState"] = this.initGridState;`

Thank you

Comment: Please try: `this.setState({isBusy: false, colList: columns, itemsList: data, gridData: proces(....), ...(reinitGridState ? {gridState: this.initGridState} : {})});`

Comment: Thank you @jsN00b , I didn't think this solution. 
But it doesn't work, this error occured : 
```Property 'gridState' is optional in type '{ gridState?: { skip: number; take: number; }; isbusy: false; colList: DisplayGridColumn[]; itemsList: any; gridData: DataResult; }' but required in type 'Pick<IEtablishementsState, "isbusy" | "itemsList" | "gridData" | "gridState" | "colList">'

```

Comment: Just to confirm, on my previous comment, the prop `gridData: proces(....),` needs to be properly copied. I just skipped it & also there is a typo in `proces` instead of `process`.

Comment: @jsN00b
Of course, I didn't made an idiot copy/paste

This is my code ```this.setState({ isbusy: false, colList: columns, itemsList: data, gridData: process(data, this.state.gridState), ...(reinitGridState ? {gridState: this.initGridState} : {}) }); ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a suitable solution to my problem, but I use this which is cleaner than the old colde for me :

```
            let newState = {
                isbusy: false,
                colList: columns,
                itemsList: data,
                gridData: process(data, this.state.gridState),
            }

            if (reinitGridState) {
                this.setState({
                    ...newState,
                    gridState: this.initGridState
                });
            } else {
                this.setState(newState);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can resolve the error by defining the variable type, something like this (pseudocode).

```
interface MyState {
    isbusy: boolean,
    colList: ColumnType,
    itemsList: DataType,
    gridData: GridDataType,
    gridState?: GridStateType
}

// ...

let newState: MyState = {
    isbusy: false,
    colList: columns,
    itemsList: data,
    gridData: process(data, this.state.gridState),
}

if (reinitGridState)
    newState.gridState = this.initGridState;

this.setState(newState);
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution.
But it doesn't work, an error occured ```Property 'gridState' is optional in type '{ gridState?: { skip: number; take: number; }; isbusy: false; colList: DisplayGridColumn[]; itemsList: any; gridData: DataResult; }' but required in type 'Pick<IEtablishementsState, "isbusy" | "itemsList" | "gridData" | "gridState" | "colList">' ```

Comment: Is that happening in the setState() call? You may also need to explicitly type the state. There are a few ways to do it. Take a look here, and note the signature "class App extends React.Component<MyProps, MyState>"  https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/getting-started/class_components/

Comment: If you use a functional component, you just do it when you first call the useState hook: useState<MyState>(initialState)